# ready function in Windows 8 not working

Tags: javascript, windows

I'm working on a Windows 8 application in HTML and JS. When I navigate to a specific HTML page using WinJS.Navigation.navigate, I expect the 'ready' function to run. Instead, it plays dead:

```
   (function () {
    "use strict";

    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("../pages/editcontact.html", {
        ready: function (element, options) {
            showToast("ello"); //does not run at all
        },

        unload: function () {
        },

        updateLayout: function (element, viewState, lastViewState) {
        }
    });})();
```

If I use jQuery to detect if the following code works, it will run the first time I navigate to the page, but not any time after that:

```
$(window).ready(function () {
    showToast('hi'); //runs only on first visit to page
});
```

What am I missing out on here? (showToast is defined and works OK, just using it as an example)

Comment: It could be somewhere else in your code.. open console to see what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check your path to .html file.
I had same problem, when it was wrong.
It requires absolute path, not relative.